# Mitwirken and mitarbeiten präposition

Tags: word-usage, preposition

When do you use mitwirken an and when do you use bei? Does this apply to mitarbeiten and sich beteiligen as well? Or is mitarbeiten always with an?

Comment: `Mitwirken` `an`, `bei` and `in` are possible (`in einem Theaterstück mitwirken`, [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mitwirken)). I would use `bei` when events or actions are involved: `mitwirken bei einer Vorführung` or `mitwirken bei dem Bau des Hauses`. Instead I would use `an` when objects are involved: `an dem Buch mitwirken` or `an dem Haus mitwirken` (but `bei dem Schreiben des Buches` <= action). However, it is just a feeling and I am not sure whether it is correct => hence no answer but only a comment.

Comment: Did you check general references, and if so, how did they not help you?

Comment: @Jan: Please specify what you mean with "general references", link or more specific clarification.

Comment: @Thomas General references like a dictionary. You don't need a link for that. Please check the site rules: questions that show no research on behalf of the OP are discouraged.

Comment: @Robert I am a native German and I don't know "general references", what is this? I know the rules of the board and I can understand the "friendly" intention of Jan, however sometimes a bit more information is helping everyone.

Comment: @Jan i don't know what you mean by general references but if you're referring to a dictionary. I have looked at several dictionaries (linguee, pons.eu, dict.cc they all do not provide a explanation on the differences and did not help, therefore I posted here. If you have a dictionary that provides such information please tell me, that would be very helpful and save a lot of time.

Comment: @Mao The point of the comment was: Questions for [tag:differences] (which your question is, although it is not tagged as such yet) should *always* state which references you checked and why they did not help you. In short: What you put in your last comment should be in the question. (If it is put there, I’ll likely upvote ;-))

Answer (score 1):

In fact there are cases where you could use both, and it wouldn't be wrong in a grammar way, but the meaning would become slightly different, depending if you want to make the fact of cooperation more important or the subject/object.

Examples:

> Ich wirke bei Frau Muster am Experiment mit.
>
> Ich wirke an dem Experiment zu Wortstellung mit.

aber:

> Ich arbeite an einem Buch, dessen Titel noch nicht genannt werden darf, mit.

You have to recognize that the part of "mit" goes behind the object (verb bracket, something unknown to the English language as far as I know). (Not best English, feel free to improve this answer)